# Add Image to the pictureBox on eventhandler

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form with a pictureBox. I want to load a picture to that box when a variable changes (with a path to this picture in this variable). So when I put a new path to the variable, the pictureBox should load this image.
I've never programmed in C#, so I tried to use some code found on the internet. 
I wrote a function like this:

```
        private void svDisplayedImagePath_OnChange(object Value)
        {  
            string fileToDisplay = (string)Value;
            pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(fileToDisplay);
        }
```

and fileToDisplay is, for example: `@"\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Pingwiny.jpg"`
or just `"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Pingwiny.jpg"`
But it seems not to work.

Putting string by the sys variable on the event handler works properly, because when I change my code to this:

```
        private void svDisplayedImagePath_OnChange(object Value)
        {  
            string fileToDisplay = (string)Value;
            label1.Text = fileToDisplay;
        }
```

the label1 changes its value to the given path/string.

So the problem is with loading an image by the path. But I've honestly never programmed in C#; I tried many solutions from the internet but with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample image paths are quite problematic since they get tranlsated.
The penguin image is not actually there when using a localised filename.

Try a different file.
Or Copy the Penguins somewhere.
Your code worked on a localised system when I typed

> "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg";

Instead of

> "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Pingwiny.jpg";

FYI (I Have a PL locale)

Comment: Oh, I was fighting with that by about 3h... That stupid penguins... Thank you!